# Does the url I provide for Facebook Like Button need to be exact or can it be one that redirects?

Tags: facebook, facebook-like

So I'm trying to generate the right URL to go in the facebook Like button. The URL is to a person's facebook page and it's generated using their facebook page's ID.

The facebook like button [developers page](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/) says that I need to include this URL in the `data-href=""` attribute in the `<div>` they provide (that the iframe is generated in).

When I go to a URL like `http://www.facebook.com/234h23o4ub23` it redirects to the right place. So I'm wondering if I can get away with using this shorter url as opposed to the url that it redirects to like for example: `http://www.facebook.com/pages/example-venue-name/234h23o4ub23`. I don't have the "example-venue-name" segment of the URL stored in my database making this method very difficult. Is that page going to register that it was liked or do I have to do the entire URL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The URL on the like button is actually just what the user will follow back, so as long as the user can follow the link, you will be fine.  The link is the unique tracker to the object so that Facebook knows distinct objects.

Comment: Interesting. I've noticed (as a Facebook n00b) that facebook "pages" have a certain number of likes associated with them. Are you saying that http://url.com/example and the page it redirects to will count as a different set of "likes" even though they go to the same place? (Being that the url is a unique tracker).

Comment: Essentially yes, UNLESS you have a "page" like button.  There are multiple ways to handle the URL identification process.